# If $\int_{0}^{t} e^{-a(t-\tau)} w(\tau) d\tau \to 0$ when $t \to \infty$ does that implies that $w(t) \to 0$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, convolution

The problem is related to the control area but I am unable to find it in the books related to control theory.

Let $a > 0$ and $t_0 < t$, if $w(t)$ is a continuous function in the interval $[t_0,\infty)$, if
\begin{equation}
   \int_{t_0}^{t} e^{-a(t-\tau)}w(\tau)d\tau \to 0 \quad \text{when } t\to\infty 
\end{equation}
does that implies that $w(t)\to0$ as $t\to\infty$?

Considering the control point of view  is intuitive to see that this might be the case, but I was not able to find how to proof.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you plug in some $w(t)$ which do not have to $w(t) \to 0$?

Comment: The conclusion does not hold in general. Perhaps there are some other properties of $w(t)$ besides continuity ?

Comment: It was corrected @StevenClark, Thank you.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, $w(t)=0$ for $t<t_0$. But I don't know if this help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **no**. A pair of counterexamples is given by the functions $\cos(e^t)$ and $\sin(e^t)$. To prove that$^{(*)}$
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^te^{-a(t-\tau)}\cos(e^{\tau})\,d\tau=0, \tag{1}
$$
even though $\cos(e^t)$ does not vanish at infinity, let's first consider the case $0<a\leq 1$. In this case, integration by parts yields
\begin{align}
&\int_0^te^{-a(t-\tau)}\cos(e^{\tau})\,d\tau=e^{-at}\int_0^te^{(a-1)\tau}
\cos(e^{\tau})\,e^{\tau}d\tau \\
&=e^{-at}\left\{e^{(a-1)t}\sin(e^t)
-(a-1)\int_0^t e^{(a-1)\tau}\sin(e^{\tau})\,d\tau\right\}. \tag{2}
\end{align}
For the first term on the RHS of $(2)$ we have
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-at}e^{(a-1)t}\sin(e^t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-t}\sin(e^t)=0, \tag{3}
$$
and for the second we have, since $a\leq 1$,
$$
\left|\int_0^t e^{(a-1)\tau}\sin(e^{\tau})\,d\tau \right|
\leq\int_0^t \left|e^{(a-1)\tau}\sin(e^{\tau})\right|\,d\tau 
\leq\int_0^t d\tau = t, \tag{4}
$$
so also
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-at}(a-1)\int_0^t e^{(a-1)\tau}\sin(e^{\tau})\,d\tau = 0. \tag{5}
$$
The case $a>1$ can be reduced to the case $0<a\leq 1$ in a finite number of integration by parts. Indeed, for any positive value of $a$ the first term in $(2)$ vanishes at infinity; the second term, on the other hand, is similar to the original integral $(1)$, with $a$ and $\cos(e^{\tau})$ replaced with $a-1$ and $\sin(e^{\tau})$, respectively. Integrating the second term by parts we obtain
$$
-(a-1)e^{-at}\left\{-e^{(a-2)t}\cos(e^t)+\cos(1)
+(a-2)\int_0^t e^{(a-2)\tau}\cos(e^{\tau})\,d\tau\right\}. \tag{6}
$$
The first two terms of $(6)$ vanish in the limit $t\to\infty$, and the remaining integral is again similar to $(1)$, but now with $a$ replaced with $a-2$. Therefore, repeating this process $n$ times, until $a-n\leq 1$, we'll arrive at an integral that vanishes in the limit $t\to\infty$.

---

$^{(*)}$ The proof for $\sin(e^t)$ is completely similar.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But this make me think that I need more assumptions regarding $w(t)$. Because $w(t) = cos(e^\tau)$ is a function such that its oscillations grows  infinitely, which is not realistic. I'm not complaining about your answer. Just thinking what other assumption I need to be close to the range of functions $w(t)$ that are reasonable. Thank you a lot.